# Using Mono to Click the Mouse in C# - Mac OS

Tags: c#, macos, mono, click, mouseevent

I have written an application (wpf - will Mono translate this for a Mac?) that I wish to somehow port across to Mac OS X. This application involves using user32.dll to perform a mouse click (something like this):

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern void mouse_event(int dwFlags, int dx, int dy, int dwData, int dwExtraInfo);
 mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0);
 mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

I have heard Mono is useful for making applications for multiple platforms - is there a way that I can use this to make my code compatible with a Mac?

If not, is there a way that I can invoke a mouse click using the Mac equivalent of user32.dll? And a way to detect whether the program is running in Windows or Mac OS to choose which bit of code to run?

Comment: are you trying to generate the mouse click against something in your application, or against another application

Comment: I'm trying to click in another application - my app is minimised while it runs.

Comment: Mono is not compatible with WPF. You need to use WinForms. I have spent a lot of time googling a Mac equivalent of user32.dll, I was unable to find a 'managed' version of mouse_event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mono does not support WPF and currently has no future plans to support it. I looked into this on the weekend myself.

If you are going to use mono with GUI applications, I advise you use WinForms instead as this is implemented in Mono.

Here is the full list of Mono implemented features - http://mono-project.com/Compatibility

Comment: This does not answer the question; he is asking if there is an equivalent way to simulate a mouse click using Mono on OS X, not whether it is possible to port over a WPF application.

Answer (score 1):

Mono currently does not plan to support WPF see [Link](http://www.mono-project.com/WPF).
Take a look at this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/580970/running-a-c-wpf-application-on-a-mac) to see if it helps and you may want to look into using Silverlight since it is supported by Microsoft on the Mac.

Answer (score 1):

Also you are calling a Win32 native function - those are not supported on Mac. Your best bet would be using cross-platform .NET-strict code.

Comment: Do you know what .NET-strict code I can use to perform a mouse click? I have looked into it before but could not find how to do it without using user32.dll...

Comment: It is a capability tied to the system - you have to invoke the API directly in Windows because there is no .NET implementation for it. There is similar capability available for Mac (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483657/performing-a-double-click-using-cgeventcreatemouseevent) but I am not sure you can use it in Mono.

Answer (score 0):

You can try looking at Apple's CG API, there is a function [CGEventCreateMouseEvent](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/QuartzEventServicesRef/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGEventCreateMouseEvent)