# C# -SQL Server app run on a Mac?

Tags: .net, porting

What are the chances of getting a C# and SQL Server app running on a Mac?

If it is not possible outright, then are there at least some components of the app that would not need to be rewritten for a port to Mac?

Comment: You might get C# running using Mono, but SQL Server locally on the Mac - forget it. You could connect to a SQL Server instance on some other (Windows) machine, of course.... or use a different database (like PostgreSQL).

Answer (score 2):

There is Mono, so you can have C# apps on the Mac.  But is it a WinForms app or WPF?

[Can we run a C#/WPF application on Mac OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/580970/running-a-c-wpf-application-on-a-mac)

SQL Server isn't going to run on a Mac.

What about virtualization?