# Best patern or recommandation for a C# project targeting WPF and later Mac

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm currently stating the development of a C# application witch will manly focus Windows platform but we would be possible to port it to Mac later on.
We're ties to C# because some of the core logic is already written in C#.

What can you recommend me, i don't really have the experience of those kind of choices ? 
Is it possible to build an application in C# and targeting Windows (using WPF) and the port it using Mono to mac ?

Witch pattern should i use ? MVVM, a classic MVC or something else ?

Thanks,

Comment: This is a discussion question, and isn't really appropriate here. See the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask). Also see [Running a C#/WPF application on a Mac](http://stackoverflow.com/q/580970/62576).

Comment: I already tried Silverlight but it's not enough for my purposes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WPF isn't supported by Mono. It's going to be very difficult to get WPF working on MAC OSX. As far as I know, the only way to do is via [XWT](https://github.com/mono/xwt/tree/master/Xwt.WPF). But I'm not intimately familiar with it.

Comment: I know that WPF isn't supported by Mono but is there a way to keep the Core separated to the UI so that you can compile to Mono afterward building a proper UI for it.
If yes witch patern or framework should i use ?

Comment: @user1869531 Yeah. Use MVVM with WPF. Keep all of the Model code out of the UI project.