# How to create high-dpi console applications on macOS with C# (if it is possible at all)?

Tags: c#, macos, retina-display, highdpi, dpi-aware

I have a simple c# console application that builds a fractal. I use Visual Studio Community on macOS. I create a bitmap of a certain size (wxh). For every pixel a color is assigned with `.SetPixel`, based on the calculated mandelbrotnumber.

```
class Form1 : Form
{
  //..
  public Form1()
  {
    //..
    AutoScaleMode = AutoScaleMode.Dpi;
  }
  //..
  private void DrawMandelbrot(object o, PaintEventArgs ea)
  {
    Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(w, h);
    mandelb = CreateMandelbrot(bm);
    ea.Graphics.DrawImage(mandelb, xMandelb, yMandelb, w, h);
  }
}
```

This works fine, except I have a high dpi retina screen and the bitmaps look very pixelated.

I tried things like:

```
        Graphics graphics = this.CreateGraphics();
        dpiX = graphics.DpiX;
```

to get a dpi, but this just gives me 96, which is the resolution of the `Form`, not of the screen.

I tried `bm.SetResolution(144.0F, 144.0F);` directly after creating the bitmap, with no succes.

I tried more complex approaches like found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5977445/how-to-get-windows-display-settings) but that just crashes the program. Probably (?) because I'm on macos, all solutions that are promoted that suggest loading .dll's like `[DllImport("user32.dll")]` dont work : `System.DllNotFoundException: user32.dll`.

I tried adding `this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(200F, 200F);` to the method that initializes the `Form`.

Even switching to [WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/580970/can-we-run-a-c-wpf-application-on-mac-os-x) seems to be problematic, if it's even possible at all on macOS. Wondering if it is even possible at all using C#?

I don't need the whole program to render for the retina dpi, but creating a bitmap pixel by pixel probably needs another approach to get high resolution images? It would be acceptable to simply make the bitmap smaller, but at a higher resolution. Of course the nicest solution would be to create the complete `Form` application with a few line of code on a high dpi-resolution, based on the available dpi of the screen, without rewriting the whole application as

The .NET documentation is really useless, so I hope someone here has a solution.

PS: instead of just downvoting my post, i'd rather hear what the critique on my post is. Is it a duplicate? I'm glad to hear where I can find the answer, have been searching for hours. You need more code? Happy to provide...

Answer (score 0):

**Visual Studio 2017 for Mac Support for macOS/OS X Development**

Visual Studio 2017 for Mac enables you to build **console** applications and **Cocoa** (desktop) applications for macOS.
[visualstudio.com](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/productinfo/vs2017-compatibility-mac#developMacOS)

That is, NO .NET Winforms and WPF.

You could start here:
[macOS development with Visual Studio for Mac.](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/mac/)

(Hint: It's Xamarin.Mac guides)

Comment: thanks for the reaction. Do I understand you correctly that it is impossible to create a console application that will render properly for a retinascreen? And, the application aside, wouldn't it be possible to create a bitmap with a higher resolution? When I use `SetResolution(144.0F, 144.0F)` it doesnt seem to have any impact on size, but I think I'm missing something...